# HAProxy - Redirect scheme to HTTPS by keeping the same HTTP method (POST)

Tags: ssl, redirect, https, haproxy, http-method

I'm using HAProxy 1.6

I'm forcing https usage. Therefore in my backend I'm redirecting http to https.
For that I'm using the following code:

```
backend my-app-name
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    [...]
```

This is working well but if my http request is done using POST Method it seems that redirect scheme will change the method to GET.

I saw that in the [documentation of HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.com/doc/aloha/7.0/haproxy/http_redirection.html#scheme-redirection) concerning HTTP redirection we can change the HTTP code to 308. But I cannot change the behavior of my current application.

How can I redirect to https using HAProxy and keeping my original HTTP Method?

Answer (score 1):

as you almost said, you could do the following:

```
backend my-app-name
       redirect scheme https code 308 if !{ ssl_fc }
```

haproxy will return 308 (instead of 302). I am not sure how your application is involved. If its sits behind haproxy it will never notice the first non-https requests. And for example, any browser will do a second request via https and the same HTTP verb, i.e. keeping the POST.

Comment: I'm not in position of testing it now has we manually changed our endpoints to https. In the use case I was describing, it was a Mobile App that was sitting behind haproxy trying to contact to an API. All the endpoints were hard coded inside the app pointing to "http".

Answer (score 0):

**Redirects**

Use the http-request redirect configuration directive to reroute HTTP traffic. These send back an HTTP redirect response to the client and then the client makes a new request to the new resource. When performing a redirection, HAProxy Enterprise responds directly to the client; it does not forward any traffic to the server.

You can specify the HTTP status code to return by setting the code parameter. Use any of the following:

Code   Meaning

---

`301`    Permanent move

`302`    Temporary move should not be cached by the client. This is the default value if no code is configured

`303`    Similar to 302, but the browser must fetch the new location using a GET

`307`    Similar to 302, but the browser must reuse the same method as the one from the original request

`308`    Similar to 301, but the browser must reuse the same method as the one from the original request